# Is there a way to pass and use an address of a reference type/value type across an app doamin? (C#)

Tags: c#, plugins, pass-by-reference, appdomain

I have an application and a set of plug-ins. They communicate across an app domain.

What I need is a way for the application to send an object (user defined or C# int, double, string, etc.) across the app domain boundary, allow the plug-in to edit it directly (i.e. the address, like a pointer) and then return and have the object keep the value as was set by the plugin.

Also, I do not want to have to use "Unsafe" code in my application.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of the definition of an app-domain that you **can't** do this.

If you don't want to marshal the value of an object across the app-domain boundary, the best you can do is have some kind of callback for the plugin to set the value within the original app-domain.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. The callback is a good recommendation, though, and I'll probably wind up implementing that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Addresses can only be used in unsafe code. I doubt you can reachout side of your app domain.

You can create classes that inherit from `MarshalByRefObject` and it will create a proxy for you to use.

Answer (score 1):

Not as such - the app domain is quite a strict boundary. You would need to code a wrapper layer to pass the serialised object across and set the object on the original side to the value passed back.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit your class from `MarshalByRefObject`. Then it can be called via appdomain boundary. But if you use your class directly you'll get the assembly loaded into your main domain. To avoid this create an interface and put it in your main assembly or some third assembly. And get the reference to this interface instead:

```
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");
return (IMyClass)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("MyLib.MyClass", "MyLib");
```